# need to use jquery-1.min.js and jquery.min.js together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use both below files but just one of the can work if both of the use in pae

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery-1.min.js"></script>//just this work
```

Or if change order

```
<script src="jquery-1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>//just this work
```

I use a drag and drop plugin , this need jquery.min.js and my theme need to jquery-1.min.js for be responsive

Comment: I don't really understand what you want

Comment: So you need to use both, but are only able to use one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: @lan No it dosnt work

Comment: You can use any plugins of jQuery together with jQuery library. Make sure jQuery library is loaded first. It should come first in your page.

Comment: I check many moods but it dosnt work together . @amol01

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this when you use noConflict.

```
<!-- load jQuery-1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_min = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_min = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Now whenever you need one of these files you can do this.

```
//example
$jQuery_min('.selector').live('click', function(){  
    //do something  
});
```

If it still wont work I dont know anymore... This is the way everybody does it. Quick google search.

Comment: Unfurtchanelly no @Mike

Comment: src=""jquery.min.js""> fix this little bit haha i fcked up, might work then